# Not reading the question then closing it for duplicate

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I've asked a question where I want to get the domain name of an url like if the url is `http://www.abv.bg/` the the domain will be `abv.bg`. However they point me the previous questions where it has been asked something else or there is no correct answer.

The question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263758/how-to-get-the-domain-name-from-an-url-with-php

Comment: You got off to a bad start by editing out the auto inserted "duplicate question" text

Comment: The original question wanted to go from `www.google.com | google.com -> google.com` and you want to go from `www.abv.bg | abv.bg -> abv.bg`. That is the same question, I'm not sure why you feel otherwise. I also don't really see a question in this post, are you asking for an extended explanation of why it was closed, or..?

Comment: Just in case you're wondering why you're being downvoted here: it's fine to post here if you think your question was wrongly close, however your title accuses others of not reading your question when in fact it was you who did not read the question linked as duplicate. That generally does not go down well.

Comment: @ShawnChin, So you are saying that if a question was asked in the past and did not get a right answer then you should not ask it again? As I said here "or there is no correct answer" at the pointed question.

Comment: I'm saying that either you haven't read the other questions well enough, or you haven't explained yourself well enough. Either way, most readers will interpret your current question such that you'll end up getting similar answers to the other questions.

Answer (score 18):

Looks like a dup to me. The linked question contain answers that can solve your problem (and a bit more).

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1974074/115845) uses `parse_url` and `str_ireplace` to make the following transformation:

```
http://www.google.com/ ->           google.com
http://google.com/something/else -> google.com
http://www.abv.bg ->                abv.bg
http://abv.bg ->                    abv.bg
```

which is similar to what you're asking, no?

*P.S. consider using `preg_replace("/^www\./", "", $domain)` instead of `str_ireplace` to avoid inadvertently replacing too much e.g. for cases like "http://www.somewww.com/".*

---

From your updates, I can just about guess what you're trying to achieve, i.e. truncate domain name to a single subdomain after the [public](http://publicsuffix.org/) [suffix](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) (effective TLD). I've given you a reopen vote but you'll have to do a lot better to convince others. Simply listing some examples with no explanation is hardly a question.

Had you spent as much effort on your question as you did fighting your case here and in the comments, you'd probably have gotten a sensible solution by now.

*P.S. If I my second attempt at understanding your question is not too far off, then you might find [this blog post](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2011/03/17/detect-subdomains-using-effective-tlds/) useful. In short, regdom provide [libraries](http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-lib-downloads/) in several languages (including PHP) that can do that for you.*

Comment: Why you are upvotin!? It is wrong! It doesn't handle http://www.bgpoeti.start.bg/ !!!

Comment: This answers the question as you have currently framed it. How should bgpoeti.start.bg be handled? Your question says nothing of it. Try editing your question with more details and it might have a chance of getting reopened.

Comment: I didn't frame it, examples nic.tr and metu.edu.tr are still there.

Comment: I see you've made [another attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8272805/115845) at the question. I've added an answer.